# JMeter - How can I send random number of payload lines for a REST service payload?

Tags: jmeter

The "Payload" picture below shows 3 line items for GROUND_SERVICE and all the values such as SERVICE_TYPE_CODE, ORIG_ZIP, DEST_ZIP, UNITS_SHIPPED, START_DATE will have to be parameterized. I cannot always send request for 3 GROUND_SERVICE line items. I need to send random number of GROUND_SERVICE lines, in this case between 1 to 3. In reality I will have about 20 line items. How can I do that while parameterizing all the values within GROUND_SERVICE element?

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhWLB.png)

**EDITED QUESTION BELOW AFTER RECEIVING DMITRI'S SUGGESTION:**

I think the suggested code allows me to send random number of GROUND_SERVICE blocks, and if so solves half of my problem. However, I cannot randomize the data elements such as ORIG_ZIP, UNITS_SHIPPED, etc. They have to be pulled from CSV file. How can I do that? Just to be clear, I made up these data elements to protect sensitive data. In reality the Request contains different kind of data elements with test data that go through a rule engine, and therefore I must pull actual data from CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler you want to parameterize
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy

   def writer = new StringWriter()
   def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

   static def getRandomGroundServices(MarkupBuilder xml) {
       1.upto(RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 4), { number ->
           xml.GROUND_SERVICES() {
               GROUND_SERVICE() {
                   SERVICE_TYPE_CODE(number + "DAY")
                   ORIG_ZIP(RandomUtils.nextInt(11111, 99999))
                   UNITS_SHIPPED(RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 10))
                   START_DATE(new Date().plus(number).format('yyyy-MM-dd'))

               }
           }
       })
   };

   getRandomGroundServices(xml)

   vars.put('payload', writer.toString())
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, now you can refer the random payload as `${payload}` where required:

   [image]
4. Each time you run the request different number of `GROUND_SERVICE` elements will be sent to the backend with random UNITS_SHIPPED and ORIG_ZIP

   [image]

References:

- [Groovy: Creating XML](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Dmitri - I see that you randomized the values within payload elements. However, my need is to randomize the number of payload blocks (GROUND_SERVICE) while picking up different values from CSV file for payload elements. In this case I have 3 blocks of GROUND_SERVICE. I want to sometimes send only 1 GROUND_SERVICE block and sometimes 3 or 2 of them randomly. At the same time ORIG_ZIP, UNITS_SHIPPED, etc should pull data from CSV file.